# Insert tabs instead of spaces

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In my C++ document, I want to insert a tab when I press tab. Under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Tabs` I chose to `Keep tabs`. However, when I press tab, Visual Studio still inserts 4 spaces. This seems to be because I used spaces in a previous section of the file.

How do I disable this "smart" insertion of spaces, just using tabs all the time?

Answer (score 1):

For me it started adding tabs when I made `Indent size` same as `Tab size`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open settings by pressing Ctrl+,

search for "Detect Indentation"

Uncheck the check box

Then uncheck the "Insert spaces" check box also.

Working fine for me.